# Torrent Seeding is not working (Libtorrent-Python)

Tags: python, seeding, torrent, libtorrent

I'm trying to generate a torrent and seed it with python libtorrent, it generates the torrent, but doesn't seed it. I tried to open the generated magnetic link with several Bittorrent clients but cannot download the file.

I am using libtorrent 1.0.7-1build1 with Python3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

My question is related to that issue:
[Python Libtorrent doesn't seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090466/python-libtorrent-doesnt-seed/43536628#43536628)

```
import sys
import time
import libtorrent as lt

videoFile = "/path/to/video/XXX.mp4"
workingPath = "/path/to/video"

tmpPath = "/tmp"
currentDir = "."

fs = lt.file_storage()
lt.add_files(fs, videoFile)
t = lt.create_torrent(fs)
t.add_tracker("udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80")
t.add_tracker("wss://tracker.openwebtorrent.com")
t.add_tracker("wss://tracker.btorrent.xyz")
t.add_tracker("wss://tracker.fastcast.nz")

t.set_creator("My Torrent")
t.set_comment("Test")
lt.set_piece_hashes(t, workingPath)
torrent = t.generate()

f = open(workingPath+"/"+"mytorrent.torrent", "wb")
f.write(lt.bencode(torrent))
f.close()

ps = lt.proxy_settings()
ps.type = lt.proxy_type.http
ps.hostname = "hostname.de"
ps.port = 1003

ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
ses.set_proxy(ps)
ses.set_web_seed_proxy(ps)

handle = ses.add_torrent({'ti': lt.torrent_info(torrent), 'save_path': currentDir, 'seed_mode': True, 'upload_mode':True, 'super_seeding':True})

print(lt.make_magnet_uri(lt.torrent_info(torrent)))

while handle.is_seed():
    s = handle.status()
    state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
      'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']

    print('\r%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % \
      (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, s.num_peers, state_str[s.state]))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two issues. First, I had an URL rewriting for all http requests to https in my webserver, so port 6881 wasn't reached.
Second, I didn't start my script from the directory where my media file was located. So putting "." for the 'save_path' location was not correct but should be the full path where the media file is located. Works fine now.

old:

```
handle = ses.add_torrent({'ti': lt.torrent_info(torrent), 'save_path': currentDir, 'seed_mode': True, 'upload_mode':True, 'super_seeding':True})
```

new:

```
handle = ses.add_torrent({'ti': lt.torrent_info(torrent), 'save_path': workingPath, 'seed_mode': True, 'upload_mode':True, 'super_seeding':True})
```